# Python 2.x - Why are strings contained a list not encoded in output?

Tags: python, encoding

When I run this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: windows-1250
lst = ['č']
s = 'č'
print lst
print s
```

I get this output:

```
['\xc4\x8d']
č
```

Why do they look different?

Comment: It is just the repr representation, there is no actuall difference `'č' == '\xc4\x8d' = True`,  in python 3 you would actually see  `'č'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Theory

`print s` calls `s.__str__()`, which returns an encoded string.

However, `print lst` calls `lst.__str__()` which in turn calls `__repr__()` on the members of the list. Unlike `__str__`, `__repr__` which does **not** return an encoded string.

## Practice

You can confirm this with the following test code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "__str__ was called"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "__repr__ was called"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print Test()
    print [Test(), Test()]
```

Which will output:

```
__str__ was called
[__repr__ was called, __repr__ was called]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to programing and confused with all this encoding. If I have a csv or .doc file is there a quick way to find out an encoding?

Comment: @HrvojeTopić This is a whole other topic. Here are a few resources: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: There is no way to find the encoding, you can only use heuristics. This has nothing to do with programming - a human being won't have a way to know the encoding either. Using BOM can help.

Comment: @HrvojeTopić Why does python show `s` as `'\xc4\x8d'` if I do `str(s)`? If all that `print s` does is converting it to string, so the outputs should be identical